Where am I supposed to store my MP3s for the macOS Music app to monitor?
The Music app seems to default to this convoluted path with multiple duplicate entries when I reset it through settings:
~/Music/Music/Media/Music/.
However, it's not obvious at all where the actual music is supposed to be stored.
No matter where on that path I place my MP3s (~/Music/, ~/Music/Music/Media/, etc), it doesn't seem to recognize them:

Which folder does the Music app monitor for local files?

Starting with iTunes many years ago, Apple software for this manages the filesystem storage for music and you get control over the media folder location, but not control over the layout it has programmed.
You will want choose:

change where the app stores files
import your files and let Music app manage the library organization
Disable the organization and still import the files
Choose a different music player option

Here are some links to get started on research for the Apple solutions implementation.

https://support.apple.com/guide/music/change-where-music-files-are-stored-mus69248042d/mac
https://support.apple.com/guide/music/import-settings-muscd653d63/mac


Which folder does the Music app monitor for local files?
On my Mac, I have a folder called Automatically Add to Music, which is under ~/Music/Music/Media.
That same path has a subfolder called Music, and all my music is inside that, sorted the way that Music.app sorts it.

If I add a file to that "automatic" folder, then it will be imported into my Music.app's library.
That's the only 'monitored' location. If I just add a file to any other part of the hierarchy, it won't get added: it will just sit there.
The "library" of audio files is for Music.app to manage, it's not for you to edit in the Finder.
If you want to know where your music library is located, you can see that in app's Settings.


Can I make it not sort anything? Just keep things as they are inside Automatically Add to Music.

@gargoylebident No: that's a special folder that moves and sorts anything put there. You can organize your own music how you want (if you want to), but you'll need to turn off copying to a central library; and you still need to "add" that music to the app's database, ideally by dragging the files onto the app.

If you want macOS Music to track your MP3s, you have several storage options.
The first option is related to the default music folder, meaning you can place your MP3 files in the default music folder located in your user directory. This folder is automatically tracked by Music. You can access it at:

For example, if your username is "John," the path would be:

The second option is a dedicated folder: If you want to keep your files organized, you can create a new folder anywhere on your Mac and have Music keep an eye on it. Let's say you create a folder called "MyMusic" on your desktop:

Once you've created the folder, open the Music app, go to Settings, click Files, and add the MyMusic folder to the list of locations that the Music app monitors.
By storing your MP3 files in the default Music folder or a custom folder you've specified in the Music app settings, you ensure that the Music app can easily find and manage your music library.

Are you sure that putting tracks into /Users/NAME/Music will put them into the Music application automatically? I have a ~/Music/Music/Automatically Add to Music directory (created by default) which is monitored by Music, not sure it works in other directories.
